# Running updateSQL for the first time gives database returned ROLLBACK error DatabaseException

Tags: liquibase

I am using Liquibase v3.9 with PostgreSQL v11 for the first time.
When testing out my changelog for the very first time I run updateSQL to see the output of the SQL that will be run against the database. I get this error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The database returned ROLLBACK, so the transaction cannot be committed. Transaction failure cause is <<ERROR: relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist
      Position: 22>>
    For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because updateSQL is expecting databasechangelog table to exist, and if this is the first time you are running Liquibase against the database then those tables won't exist yet (they get created the first time you run liquibase update).

I do think this is a valid use case for running updateSQL, you can request this feature here:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues

Answer (score 0):

```
relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist
```

I was with this issue using PostgreSQL in a container.

Then I realized the memory limit given to PostgreSQL was insufficient.

After Increasing PostgreSQL limit memory to 512MiB the problem was solved.

Comment: Can you describe how you did that?

Comment: That was long time ago and I don't really remember, but I believe that I've just increased the docker container memory limit with the argument '--limit-memory` to the swarm service.

Comment: Is there any specific property you specified which caused the error to have the full name of table public.databasechangeloglock , instead of just databasechangeloglock, which is the case for me. I think it looks for the table in a different schema and throws this error as a result.

Comment: IDK, but I think it can be related to different liquibase version.